# Dash sign changing behavior when replacing column values in dataframe with dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

I'm trying to replace the values of a column in a dataframe with values in a dictionary. The unmodified column looks like this (trimmed)

```
>>> df.Class.head(10)

0    AA-
1    AA+
2    AA
3    BBB-
4    AAA
5    AA-
6    AA
7    A-
8    AA+
9    A+
Name: Class, dtype: object
```

While my dictionary is the following:

```
>>> ratingsDict

{'AAA': 'Class AAA',
 'AA+': 'Class AA',
 'AA': 'Class AA',
 'AA−': 'Class AA',
 'A+': 'Class A',
 'A': 'Class A',
 'A−': 'Class A',
 'BBB+': 'Class BBB',
 'BBB': 'Class BBB',
 'BBB−': 'Class BBB',
 'BB+': 'Class BB',
 'BB': 'Class BB',
 'BB−': 'Class BB',
 'B+': 'Class B',
 'B': 'Class B',
 'B−': 'Class B',
 'C': 'Class C'}
```

By using the following code, I'm trying to replace the column values with the values in the dictionary.

```
df.Class = df.Class.replace(ratingsDict)
```

Which works fine for most values, except for the ones ending in with a dash ("-")

```
0    AA-
1    Class AA
2    Class AA
3    BBB-
4    Class AAA
5    AA-
6    Class AA
7    A-
8    Class AA
9    Class A
Name: Class, dtype: object
```

Any ideas what might be happening? Thanks.

Comment: It seems your dash in dictionary "−" is different from your dash in dataframe "-"... If you change the dashes in your dictionary, probably your code will work.

Comment: I fixed it, by creating the dictionary directly in code. Don't really know where the problem was coming from, but originally I was creating the dictionary from a csv file, which didn't have any leading or trailing spaces (so that wasn't the issue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the dash "-" format: dash in dictionary "−" is different from the dash in dataframe "-".

Probably the character is represented in a different format in the .csv file you were using.

When you create the dictionary directly in your code, the dash format is the same as the represented one in the dataframe: "-". And, thus, your code works.